# HTML SVG How to change elements to visible/hidden on mouse hover?

Tags: css, html, svg

I have something like this:

```
<circle class="node" cx="" cy="" r="10" fill="green" />
<text class="description" x="-20" y="-10">Lorem description</text>
```

I try to set `description` to hidden/visible on hover over green svg circle using pure CSS or if it not possible using javascript. I don't want/can change `description` from `class` to `id`.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you just need to add this CSS, as `.description` is immediately preceded by `.node`

```
.node:hover + .description { visibility: visible}
```

and that's done. This will track hover action on the element with class `.node` and will make its next adjacent element with class `.description` to go visible when it (`.node`) is hovered.

Here is the **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/4fbdearL/1/)**

Now suppose `.description` is NOT immediately preceded by `.node` and some other elements are located between both of them, then you can add following CSS

```
.node:hover ~ .description { visibility: visible}
```

The `~` combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent.

So in both the cases while using this CSS selector technique for your case `.node` should be located before `.description`

Answer (score 0):

Add this css class and it must work fine.

```
.node:hover + .description { visibility: visible}
```